# How to get files content from google drive, drop-box storage applications in android grammatically using intent

Tags: android, dropbox, box, drive

I want to open particular installed application (ex-drive, drop-box, box and cloud so.on) using intent to fetch file or image from that application, read content and get file path to save into server. so please help me to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

user their api or sdk to access the service externally